# Can i pass parameter from one page to another page during pop method ? In ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

parameter can be passed from one to another during push but how to do the same during pop ??

```
  showfilter(){
    this.navCtrl.push(FilterPage,{
      fulldetail : this.selectedarea 
    }); 
  }
```

how to do the same during pop ????
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [Navcontroller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#pop), the pop funtion does not have the params parameter like [push function](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#push)

You could use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/).

```
  events.publish('details:send', this.selectedarea);
```

and in the receiving page,

```
events.subscribe('details:send',(s)=>{ console.log(s)});
```

Comment: Agreed, `Events` are in my opinion one of the best ways of passing around information, creates very versatile and easily extendable functionality